# A word for someone who pathologically snoops through people's things

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for someone who doesn't necessarily steal anything but would compulsively snoop through someone's things if left alone, similar to kleptomaniac (someone who would compulsively steal things)?

Comment: Why are you sure that there is a word for this? Does a word exist in your native languages?

Answer (score 2):

The word [*snoop*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snoop) also has a noun form:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **verb**
>   : to look or pry especially in a sneaking or meddlesome manner
>
> **noun**
>   : one that snoops

So, somebody who snoops is a . . . *snoop*.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a term that's as technical as *kleptomaniac* is for a compulsive thief. A technical phrase might be "pathological nosiness" or "pathological snooping".

As Jason Bassford notes, you can use ***snoop*** as a noun here. There are also idioms and slang in particular dialects, such as ***nosy parker***.

It's also a feature of *relationship obsessive compulsive disorder*, but it exists independently of that diagnosis, and is only one feature of it.